# bundle install on ruby on rails throwing mingw32 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite3-ruby

I'm very new on ruby and trying to install it for the first time on my machine my it's giving me these error i've already installed sqlite3 on my machine I don't know what is the cause please help

> warning: Public keyring not found; have you run 'pacman-key --init'?
> error: mingw32: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
> error: keyring is not writable
> error: mingw64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
> error: keyring is not writable
> error: ucrt64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
> error: keyring is not writable
> error: clang64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
> error: keyring is not writable
> error: msys: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
> error: keyring is not writable
> error: database 'mingw32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
> error: database 'mingw64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
> error: database 'ucrt64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
> error: database 'clang64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
> error: database 'msys' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

image is attached for the reference [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYFco.png)

Comment: Mingw32 looks like you are on windows. Do you use the rubyinstaller https://rubyinstaller.org/ ?

Comment: @OliverGaida yes!

Answer (score 3):

Fully remove the Ruby install, via control panel and ensure that all directories where Ruby has installed are deleted.

Then re-run the installation program BUT right click the icon and use "run as Administrator". This worked for me and I had the same issue.